# Downloading a repository from Github

Tags: software-installation, wget

I want to download and install fuse, I am following [this tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs/)

> Download and compile latest version of fuse source code. For this
>   article, we are using fuse version 3.5. Following the set of command
>   will compile fuse and add fuse module in the kernel.

```
cd /usr/src/
wget https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/releases/download/fuse-3.5.0/fuse-3.5.0.tar.xz
```

I have executed the above 2 commands, but seems that it has not worked - output:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/48296177/f5f40080-6080-11e9-831e-924025a26137?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20190819%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190819T032718Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=9daad2fc48ac63c665e7bb3c4af49d43b4d9f04170b13e31cd134f8f4bf37c72&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dfuse-3.5.0.tar.xz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream [following]
--2019-08-19 03:27:18--  https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/48296177/f5f40080-6080-11e9-831e-924025a26137?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20190819%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190819T032718Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=9daad2fc48ac63c665e7bb3c4af49d43b4d9f04170b13e31cd134f8f4bf37c72&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dfuse-3.5.0.tar.xz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
Resolving github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com (github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.217.36.188
Connecting to github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com (github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.217.36.188|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1021676 (998K) [application/octet-stream]
fuse-3.5.0.tar.xz: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘fuse-3.5.0.tar.xz’ (Success).
```

I cannot see any code being downloaded in: `/usr/src`

Comment: Switch directories to one you have write access to.

Comment: You will see that in the tutorial the '#' sign is used at the beginning of each code block. This denotes raised privileges which under Ubuntu implies the use of sudo, this way you will have write access to /usr/src.

Comment: @andrew.46, thanks a lot. I had no idea # means super user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put sudo before wget.

> fuse-3.5.0.tar.xz: Permission denied
>   Cannot write to ‘fuse-3.5.0.tar.xz’ (Success).

This portion suggests that your system refuses to write fuse-3.5.0.tar.xz on usr/src/ because you do not have the privilege.